# A populated Table returns no rows

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html-table

In a web application I am writing, I populate a HTML table with a button press; after the table is populated, then the user can click another button to export the table in a CSV file.

The issue is that, while the table is properly populated at he first button pressing, it appears to be empty when the application query it at the second button press.

A few code to explain the issue:
the HTML in ASPX page

```
<asp:Button ID="BTNPopulate" runat="server" Text="Populate" />
<table id="Table1" style="border-width: 1px; border-color: Black; padding: 5px" cellspacing="0" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="BTNExport" runat="server" Text="Export" />
```

now the first button

```
Protected Sub BTNTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNTest.Click
Dim row As HtmlTableRow
        Dim cell As HtmlTableCell
        row = New HtmlTableRow()
        row.BgColor = "Gray"
        cell = New HtmlTableCell()
        cell.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("Test cell"))
        row.Cells.Add(cell)
        Table1.Rows.Add(row)
end sub
```

and the table is properly populated.
I was unable to obtain any info from it and in fact if I call the *.Rows.Count* method anyway in the second button click code-behind

```
Protected Sub BTNExport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNExport.Click

    Response.ContentType = "text/csv"
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='PFExport.csv'")

    CSVBuilder.Append(Table1.Rows.Count)

    Response.Write(CSVBuilder.ToString)
    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

the result in the file is always 0.
On the other hand, if I call the same *.Rows.Count* property at the end of the populate part of the code, it properly returns the result.
I tried to use the ASPTable instead of the HTMLTable, but the issue is the same.

I assume I am missing something basic here, not sure what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET (or anything on the web ftm) works over HTTP. HTTP is stateless. That means that whatever you do in one request is completely lost when you make a new request.

ASp.NET webforms tries to hide this from you by using something called ViewState. It's essentially a hidden field which it sends back and forth to repopulate your page every time you do a roundtrip. When the server reconstructs the page, it reads the info from the ViewState that was sent in and rebuilds the page from those values.

The problem you're having is that the page is not repopulated yet when your click-handler is triggered. There's two ways to fix this.

1. (preferred): Instead of reading the data from the table in the UI, just look it up in the database again.
2. Set a flag on the page in the click-handler and populate the CSV on the `PreRender`-event.

Comment: Dear Kenneth, thanks a lot for your help.
Unfortunately the 1 way is not feasible, because the data returned are random, so they are really not repeatable. May I kindly ask you to elaborate a little on the second possibility?

Answer (score 0):

As explained by [Kenneth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1816704/kenneth), my error to think the information to be preserved between requests, while HTTP is stateless.

So I investigate this from a different perspecitve and I ended up using View State to store the information locally and retrieve it to generate the CSV at the Export button press.

So, to store the info I use

```
ViewState("TableResultsState") = CSVBuilder.ToString
```

immediately after the table is populated.

For the export button, I do

```
With Response
    .ContentType = "text/csv"
    .AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='PFExport.csv'")
    .Write(ViewState("TableResultsState").ToString)
    .Flush()
    .End()
End With
```

As the text quantity is limited, from my research I understand this should not have adverse effects.

Again, thanks to [Kenneth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1816704/kenneth) for pointing out my very basic misunderstanding.